# Unable to open images in Cross Validated questions/answers

Tags: feature-request, bug, images

I'm reading through the following post: [A layman understanding of the difference between back-door and front-door adjustment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350267/a-layman-understanding-of-the-difference-between-back-door-and-front-door-adjust)

and I'm unable to open the images posted in the answer.

We used to be able to post images directly to a question or answer, but now we have to open a separate link which my company's firewall is blocking.

Is there a quick solution to accessing images?

Answer (score 5):

Well, the images are still in the post but your firewall is blocking them anyway. The URL is the same.

Apart from configuring the firewall to allow the `i.stack.imgur.com` domain, you can try to save the page in the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/save). I've just done so for that question, and you can view it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200916143607/https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350267/a-layman-understanding-of-the-difference-between-back-door-and-front-door-adjust). The image links are now hosted under the `web.archive.org` domain, perhaps that is sufficient to trick your firewall?

Comment: Thanks that worked. Are the images stored on a separate server - is that why my firewall is blocking them?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.